# Can't access app engine dev server from local network (Netbeans)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans

I'm trying to access my dev server from a mobile phone in my local network but I always get "connection refused". My app engine application works perfectly on localhost, but I can't access it from another device.

I think that the dev server is listening only on loop interface, but I don't know how to fix it on Netbeans (i'm using Google App Engine plugin).

Any ideas? I have been looking for another questions here but I can't find a fix for Netbeans.

Thanks in advance.